# java util logging multiple log files created

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

Am trying to implement `java.util.logging` in my java awt swing app(its a .jar application). Also, i want to logging multiple java class file.
So, i created logging functionality as utility class.

Please find my `MyLog` its a utility class

```
public class MyLog {
    
    private static MyLog instance = new MyLog();
    public static MyLog getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
    
    
    public void info(String msg) {
         Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");  
            FileHandler fh;  

            try {  

                // This block configure the logger with handler and formatter  
                fh = new FileHandler("f://MyLogFile.log");  
                logger.addHandler(fh);
                SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();  
                fh.setFormatter(formatter);  

                // the following statement is used to log any messages  
                logger.info(msg);  

            } catch (SecurityException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            } catch (IOException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
    }
}
```

Please find my implementation class.

```
class AEvent extends Frame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private MyLog logProp = MyLog.getInstance();

    TextField tf;

    AEvent() {

        // create components
        tf = new TextField();
        tf.setBounds(60, 50, 170, 20);
        Button b = new Button("click me");
        b.setBounds(100, 120, 80, 30);

        // register listener
        b.addActionListener(this);// passing current instance

        // add components and set size, layout and visibility
        add(b);
        add(tf);
        setSize(300, 300);
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);
        logProp.info("My first logging message 1");

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        logProp.info("My first logging message 2");
        tf.setText("Welcome");

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws SecurityException, IOException {
        new AEvent();

    }
}
```

problem here is, logs are writting in multiple file (means, multiple `MyLogFile.log` is generated) also, `MyLogFile.log.1.lck` this type of file also its generating.

Please find the list of log file below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a Logger each and every time you write to the log, create *one* static Logger object:

```
private static final Logger logger =
    Logger.getLogger(MyLog.class.getName());

static {
    try {  
        fh = new FileHandler("f:\\MyLogFile.log");  
        SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();  
        fh.setFormatter(formatter);  
        logger.addHandler(fh);
    } catch (SecurityException | IOException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
}
```

And then your method should become simply:

```
public void info(String msg) {
    logger.info(msg);
}
```

Obviously, there isn’t much value in doing this.  Instead, every class should have its own static final Logger field.  You add no value by wrapping a Java Logger in your own logging class.

In fact, your wrapper class is making things worse, by writing all messages to a Logger with the same name.  Each class should make use of a Logger with a name that corresponds to that class's fully qualified name, which is what `Logger.getLogger(MyLog.class.getName())` does.

So, all you really need to do is add the FileHandler:

```
public class MyLog {
    private static boolean added;

    /** Make sure this class cannot be instantiated. */
    private MyLog() {
        // Deliberately empty.
    }

    public static void addFileHandler() {
        if (!added) {
            try {  
                fh = new FileHandler("f:\\MyLogFile.log");  
                SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();  
                fh.setFormatter(formatter);  
                Logger.getLogger("").addHandler(fh);
                added = true;
            } catch (SecurityException | IOException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

`Logger.getLogger("")` is the parent of all other loggers.  The others will inherit its handlers.

In your application class, change this:

```
private MyLog logProp = MyLog.getInstance();
```

to this:

```
private static final Logger logProp =
    Logger.getLogger(AEEvent.class.getName());
```

And initialize the log file handler in your main method:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    MyLog.addFileHandler();
    new AEvent();
}
```

Side note:  AWT and Swing classes need to be executed in the dedicated AWT Event Dispatch Thread, not in the main thread. You can do that with [EventQueue.invokeLater](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)):

```
public static void main(String args[])
    MyLog.addFileHandler();
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new AEvent());
}
```

Side note 2:  Slash and backslash are *not* the same character.  This is a valid Windows path:

```
"f:\\MyLogFile.log"
```

But this is not:

```
"f://MyLogFile.log"
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem: You are creating the log file in the info method.

When you first run the program it will create a log file for each call to the info method.

You should create the log file only once say in constructor.

```
package com.practice;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

public class MyLog {

private static MyLog instance = new MyLog();
private Logger logger;

public static MyLog getInstance() {
    return instance;
}


public void info(String msg) {
    logger.info(msg);

}


private MyLog() {
    FileHandler fh;
    try {
        logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");
        // This block configure the logger with handler and formatter
        fh = new FileHandler("f://MyLogFile.log");
        logger.addHandler(fh);
        SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
        fh.setFormatter(formatter);

    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyLog myLog = MyLog.getInstance();
    myLog.info("www");
    myLog.info("asa");
    myLog.info("asa");
    myLog.info("vv");
    myLog.info("ffv");
}
```

}